# windows azure ACS confirmation for user credentials

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, authentication, azure, acs, adfs2.0

I have an application on windows azure where users are authenticating by using ACS ( with ADFS 2.0).
There is a requirement that before certain actions, the user must confirm his identity by retyping his password. 
Is there some way to ask ACS to check for credentials when a user is already signed in?

For a moment I thought about checking against the cookies created for the authentication, but I am not really sure that is possible. Besides, this feels just wrong.

Any ideas? I have been trying to search for REST apis of azure's ACS but it seems there are only management api calls for ACS.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do this other than signing the user out and making them sign back in again. Even that, though, won't guarantee a password entry in all cases. If ADFS is configured for integrated auth (Kerberos), and the user is on a domain joined machine, they may never have entered their credentials and there's nothing you can do to force them to.

Comment: Thats what i thought, can you think of an alternative approach to accomplish this without having access to the user's password?